# Install admin theme inside of angular-fullstack app?

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I am currently building a component based app using angular fullstack, and am having trouble installing an admin template like blur-admin (https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/) inside my project.
How to install an admin theme easily inside my angular fullstack app?? 
Has anyone done this, or is it always done running the admin side separately and routing it on a subdomain?

Thank you :)